# Laravel - manual rendering of breadcrumbs

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, breadcrumbs

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I would like to use breadcrumbs by [davejamesmiller](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs). I have set route `Route::resource('admin/users', '\Easyk\Controllers\Admin\UsersController');` and according documentation created file `Http/breadcrumbs.php` where content is:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('admin.users.index', function ($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Users', route('admin.users.index'));
});
```

When I try in template `{!! Breadcrumbs::render() !!}` then it will render without problem. But I would like to render it manualy. According documentation I created file `config/breadcrumbs.php` with content:

```
return [
    'view' => 'partials/_breadcrumbs',
];
```

but when I try to render it there is no `$breadcrumbs` variable:

```
@if(!empty($breadcrumbs))
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li>{!! link_to_route('main', 'Home') !!}</li>
    @foreach($breadcrumbs as $bread)
        @if(isset($bread['url']))
            <li>{!! link_to($bread['url'], $bread['name']) !!}</li>
        @else
            <li>{!! $bread['name'] !!}</li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </ol>
@endif
```

Do you have any experience how to get `$breadcrumbs` variable to the view specified in file?

Answer (score 1):

I already solved it. In layout I need `{!! Breadcrumbs::renderIfExists() !!}` and then in partials/_breadcrumbs I will get `$breadcrumbs` variable. If I get it right then method `renderIfExists()` works as include.

Also in `config/breadcrumbs.php` must be dot convention:

```
return [
    'view' => 'partials._breadcrumbs',
];
```